# Slow tkinter app loading and choppy mouse

Tags: python, python-3, gui, tkinter

I have a raspberry pi 5 running a python app that uses a customtkinter UI and TCP client running on a thread along with some serial port IO on another thread.

The app loads in around 15 seconds and the mouse moves choppy.

I have the same app running very well both on windows and raspberry pi OS on another more capable system.

Even after running the tkinter UI without the threads, the result remains the same.

I want to know if I can optimize the code on the tkiner side to make it run faster or is raspberry pi too slow for this application?

The code is too large >2000 lines to be posted here.
I can link it here temporarily [-Link-](https://codeshare.io/Q8ZnX7)

Thanks in advance.